# Build keras CNN for vector

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm a beginner in ML, and was trying to solve a problem. I am given `N` vectors as input. Length of each vector is `10`. I have been given `N` labels which are 0/1. I need to train a CNN over this data that has (in mentioned order):

1. Convolution layer
2. Maxpooling
3. Dense layer
4. Softmax activation for getting binary output

I did:

```
def get_model(inputShape, filters = 32, kernel_size = 3, pool_size = 4, strides = 1):
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size))
    model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size, strides))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1))
    model.add(layers.Activation(activation='softmax'))
    model.build(inputShape)
    print(model.summary())
    return model

model = get_model((None, None, 10))
```

Then, I to test my model is build correctly, I do this: (without training)

```
x = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
x = x.reshape(1, x.shape[0], x.shape[1])
print(model.predict(x))
```

I get this output/error:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, None, 32)          992       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_1 (MaxPooling1 (None, None, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, None, 1)           33        
_________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)    (None, None, 1)           0         
=================================================================
Total params: 1,025
Trainable params: 1,025
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
None
2020-06-30 19:44:01.763782: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1753] OP_REQUIRES failed at pooling_ops_common.cc:91 : Invalid argument: Computed output size would be negative: -3 [input_size: 0, effective_filter_size: 4, stride: 1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_predict.py", line 41, in <module>
    model.predict(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1458, in predict
    return training_arrays.predict_loop(self, f, ins,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 324, in predict_loop
    batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3792, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1605, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1645, in _call_impl
    return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1745, in _call_flat
    return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 593, in call
    outputs = execute.execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  Computed output size would be negative: -3 [input_size: 0, effective_filter_size: 4, stride: 1]
     [[node max_pooling1d_1/MaxPool (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3007) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_136]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

Please suggest how i can correct this.

Comment: do you mean that your vectors have 10 timestamps and a single features? I remember you that a Conv1D receives inputs in the format (n_sample, timestamps, n_features)

Comment: Could you pls try to run: `model = get_model((None,))`?

Comment: @DanyloBaibak I get `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=1` (in get_model method)

Comment: @MarcoCerliani No, those it has 10 features

Comment: @mike and the time dimension is ?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I incorporated your feedback on `(n_sample, timestamps, n_features)`. Tried `model = get_model((None,1, 10))` to build model and `x = x.reshape(x.shape[0], 1, x.shape[1])` for testing, and it works. Thanks a lot for your feedback

Comment: @mike how can you operate MaxPooling1D on 1 timestamps ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the dimension of the `x`. It is just too small for `Conv1D(kernel_size=3)` and `MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4)`.

I added one more dimension to the `x` and reduce `kernel_size` and `pool_size`:

```
x = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=np.float32)
x = x.reshape(1, x.shape[0], x.shape[1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(filters=10, kernel_size=2)) 
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2, strides=1))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.add(layers.Activation(activation='softmax'))
model.build((None, None, 10))

model.predict(x)
```

If you need, I can share the link to the google colab file.